# Inertia.js not calling onSuccess() on delete route

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, datatables, inertiajs

I have a delete route Inertia.js so that when I delete an item, it will redirect back to the page that I am on. However, this is not calling onSuccess() function in the Inertia destroy route.

`Example.vue`

```js
deleteSubmit(id) {
    this.accountsDataTable.destroy();
    Inertia.destroy(route('installers.destroy', {id: id}), {}, { 
        preserveState: true, 
        onSuccess: () => {
            this.accountsDataTable = $('#table').DataTable({
                columnDefs: [{
                    target: 1
                }]
            });
        }
    })
},
```

`ExampleController.php`

```php
//Validate the request
//Create the installer
//Redirect back on success
return redirect()->route('installers.index')->with('success', 'Installer was successfully deleted.');
```

However, the datatable is not recreated as I want it to. Here is what it looks like before:

correct image

[image: correct image]

And this is how it is afterwards:

wrong image

[image: wrong image]

I tried changing the controller code to this:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Installer was successfully deleted');
```

However the datatable still does not show as it should.

Comment: Are you not redirecting to index page instead of back ?

Comment: I am on the index page, where I have a delete button and I am trying to redirect the user back to the index page, which works, but my onSuccess() function where I rebuild the datatable is never called

Answer (score 1):

**1:** set redirect back with message data in the controller.

```php
return redirect()->back()->with([
    'messaage' => 'Installer was successfully deleted',
])
```

**2:** HandleInertiaRequests middleware.

```php
public function share(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
        'flash' => [
            'message' => fn () => $request->session()->get('message'),
        ],
    ]);
}
```

**3:** in component.

```html
<template>
{{ $page.props.flash.message }}
</template>

<script setup>
import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'

const message = usePage().props.value.flash.message
</script>
```

docs : https://inertiajs.com/shared-data

Comment: The success message works fine, my issue is with the datatable not being rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party here, but basically, the `router.delete()` method doesn't take the same arguments as `router.post()` or `router.get()`. So you should build your request like this, with only two arguments:

```
router.delete(route('YOUR ROUTE'), {
    onSuccess: () => {
        ...
    }
    onError: () => {
        ...
    }
});
```